# Read JSON in pySpark with custom schema in GCP Dataproc

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

In GCP Dataproc (with pySpark), I am doing a task i.e. to read JSON file as per custom schema and load it in a Dataframe.

I do have following sample testing JSON:

```
{"Transactions": [{"schema": "a",
"id": "1",
"app": "testing",
"description": "JSON schema for testing purpose"}]}
```

I have created following schema:

```
custom_schema = StructType([
                      StructField("Transactions",
                         StructType([
                             StructField("schema", StringType()),
                             StructField("id", StringType()),
                             StructField("app", StringType()),
                             StructField("description", StringType())
                                   ])
                            )])
```

Reading JSON as:
`df_2 = spark.read.json(json_path, schema = custom_schema)`

Getting following results,

[image: Getting following results,]

Now, I need to check data in Dataframe, When I try to do `df_2.show()`, it is taking too much time and show as ***kernel Busy*** for hours.

I need help, that what I am missing here in code and how can I see the data in dataframe (Tabular format).

Comment: Tried with following, but did not worked.



```
custom_schema = StructType([
                      StructField("Transactions",
                         ArrayType(StructType([
                             StructField("schema", StringType()),
                             StructField("id", StringType()),
                             StructField("app", StringType()),
                             StructField("description", StringType())
                                   ]))
                            )])
```

Comment: Can you try df_2.show(5) and see if you get any results?

Comment: Yes, I tried...did not work...seems there is some issue with Dataproc cluster config as well?

Comment: Did you try submitting it as a PySpark job instead of running in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem, `df.show()` worked for me. You can try with an even simpler schema.

Comment: Finally, I was able to read JSON data. I recreated above JSON file again in a single line. Seems, it did not work earlier because it was having line gap after each element.  Now, I used following custom schema :                                          ``` custom_schema = StructType([ StructField("Transactions", ArrayType(StructType([ StructField("schema", StringType()), StructField("id", StringType()), StructField("app", StringType()), StructField("description", StringType()) ])) )]) ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your custom schema definition and the JSON file. The following code and JSON file worked for me:

### Code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("JSON test") \
    .getOrCreate()

custom_schema = StructType([
    StructField("schema", StringType(), False),
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("app", StringType(), True),
    StructField("description", StringType(), True)])

df = spark.read.format("json") \
    .schema(custom_schema) \
    .load("gs://my-bucket/transactions.json")

df.show()
```

### JSON file

The contents of `gs://my-bucket/transactions.json` is:

```
{"schema": "a", "id": "1", "app": "foo", "description": "test"}
{"schema": "b", "id": "2", "app": "bar", "description": "test2"}
```

### Output

```
+------+---+---+-----------+
|schema| id|app|description|
+------+---+---+-----------+
|     a|  1|foo|       test|
|     b|  2|bar|      test2|
+------+---+---+-----------+
```

Comment: when I do same, it give me all  `NULL` values, how can I fix it?